# re-sync to remote repo after creating new fresh git init

Tags: git, github

I have a local repo and has been up to date with my remote github (100% synced).

Case #1 : I delete the .git so now the local repos is not a git folder anymore (disconnected from the remote) then how can i re-sync again with the remote ? Assumes that I don't want to do the 'git clone' because I know that my local is already a perfect clone. I don't want to waste time by recloning and re-download the whole folders which is very big. If do the new 'git init' then set the 'remote origin' to my existing remote repo. Is it possible to re-sync again with minimum upload/download process ? How can i tell the remote that my local copy is already up to date ? in this case there should be no push/pull needed.

Case #2 : If during the 'disconnection' , I add or modify some files then do git init. will it be possible that git will check the remote and local to find only the difference . So git will flag only the new or modified files to be added/commited/pushed.

Is it possible in git ? Many SYNC application like carbon copy and synctoy , they can compare and recognize if files are completely the same so these files will be ignored from the sync list even on the first sync ( If i manually copy it before)

Comment: Case #1: I don’t think you can download any *less* because you need to get the whole Git object database. You only have the checked out worktree. The only thing you might be able to save some effort on is disk since you don’t need to checkout the worktree again, but I don’t know how to do that. (If you try to checkout the remote’s branch again, `git checkout` will complain that your untracked files would be overwritten.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first point would be done with:

```
git remote add origin <remote-repo-url> # add remote as origin
git fetch                               # 

# set branch and synch everything
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch-name> <branch-name>
git pull
```

if local and branch have the same commit history, then you can skip the branching and git pull.

The second case is normal git add, commit and push - in my view:

```
git status # get overview
git add .  # add the newly added files
git commit -m "Commit message" # commit them
git push   # push to remote
```

Comment: right after git init , All the files will be untracked. It will prevent me from doing 'pull' also if I pull (force pull to overwrite) I will re-download the whole thing again - which I already have. If possible i don't want to waste re-doing that.